# Apply scroll-snap only for x axis

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply scroll-snap-type but only for overflow-x.

I created an example. I would like to have the same behavior as Chrome in Firefox. (snap only on x axis and disabled on y axis)

If you try this example on Chrome => snap will not be applied on y axis.
if you try on Firefox             => snap will BE applied on y axis

```css
.scroller {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(320px);
    scroll-snap-destination: 0 0;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.scroller section {
    width: 1000px;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="scroller">
    <section>
        <h2>Section oneSection oneSection oneSection oneSection oneSection oneSection oneSection one</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section two</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section three</h2>
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-points-y):  It is not supported on chrome.

Comment: scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; is still supported on both browser but not scroll-snap-type-y.